# Convert linked DBF's to Access with recordnumbers

Tags: ms-access, dbf, dbase

I have an old dbase-database (made with a program programmed with clipper 5.2) which consists of multiple tables (files). The tables are linked with some sort of recordnumber, but in the source table, no recordnumber-field is found. I want to convert this database to Access and re-establish the links. I've read something about a dbf recordpointer (?) but i don't know how to extract it from the DBF.

Comment: Are index files present?  E.g. `*.idx` or `*.ndx`.

Comment: Yes, I do have *.ndx files

Comment: That is where the links are.

Comment: Can you post some code which shows this multi-table link?

Comment: It uses the function recno() to determine the recordnumber in the dbf-file... But i do not see how i can export this recordnumber from the DBF....

Comment: I don't think that this was ever considered good practice as record no's can change as tables are maintained.  But more importantly, you need to decide what the links will be in your new Access database tables.  Then establish these after you bring over the data rather than continue this unreliable procedure.  I know for sure that MS Access does not recommend using record numbers for linking tables.

Comment: If it's really necessary to retain the record no's, one option would be to use the free version of Harbour or xHarbour available on the web to restructure the DBFs to include the record no's as a new field in each table.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if recno() or some such is being used, then it suggests that the table starts at one.
Remember, you can’t update a PK autonumber in Access, BUT YOU CAN RUN append queries against such tables!!!

So link to a dBase table. When you view this table in Access does it show that incrementing column?

It should and does for me.

The above detail has not been made clear by you.

So let’s assume you see this column that increments and is NOT marked as a PK?

That is just fine (and is expected). As LONG as you see the incrementing number in that linked table then you are just fine.

This process of importing then becomes rather fast and easy.

On the create ribbon tab, just choose query design.

Drop in that linked table.

From ribbon choose make table. Enter your new local table name.

Drag the * from the table into the into the query grid (first column of grid).

You have this:

[image]

Now run the above query query (hit the run button in ribbon).

Exit (toss that query out – no need to save).

The result will be a new local table, with that number column.

Now, empty data from that local table.

(Ctrl-g to debug window)

Currentdb.execute "delete * from NewLocalTable"

Now do a compact + repair (this re-sets any autonumber columns in empty tables – might not be required – but just do it anyway). And it reclaims the empty space for that table we just emptied out.

Ok, now open that new local table in design mode. Select that first number id column, and delete it. (click on that row - likely first row - hit del key).

Now, click on first row to select the column that is first. Hit insert key to push it all down, and enter the name of the numbering column you JUST deleted. Tab key, autonumber, and then from ribbon whack the PK button (primary key button).

Close table designer. Save the design changes.

We now have an empty table with a PK autonumber column as the SAME name as what we had before.

Now, create new query, droop in linked table.

From ribbon choose append query, and enter name of new local empty table.

Drag the * into the query grid.

Run it.

We now have a local table, with PK autonumber, and the columns will match up to the linked table.

For a 10 second test?

Ctrl-g (jump to debug window).

Type in:

```
? dcount("*","linkeddBaseTabble name")
? dcount("*","NewlocalTable name")
```

The record counts should be the same.

At this point you have a local table with same columns + the PK ID autonumber column.

You can repeat the above over and over. It goes fast. 20-30 tables will not take long.

The result is now local tables, and each table will have an autonumber PK column with the same column name.

I would think the column as a linked table is “ID”, but it might be RECNO. (So use that for the local PK column names).

So you:

Link to dbase table.

Query builder – make table.

Ctrl-g to empty local table:

```
Currentdb.execute "delete * from local table name"
```

Open local table in desing - delete number column, add it back as PK autonumber.

Query builder, drop in linked table. From ribbon select append query, enter name of local table.

Drag “*” to query grid – run it.

You now have a local table, with PK autonumber same as linked table.

Move on to next table to import (add an autonumber to each table you import with above few steps.

Comment: It's important to note here that if there are deleted records in the DBF using autonumber in Access is not going to give the same result as the record numbers in the DBF table.  Access will not include the deleted records.

Comment: Agree. In fact if the table(s) in question can include the deleted records, then that would be advisable.  One might consider using the FoxPro ODBC driver as I believe that you can toggle  setting to included deleted rows.

Comment: Yes, and I'm not positive but I seem to recall that it's possible for Access to include deleted records by changing a setting (just not sure where).  What I wonder about these options is 'will the deleted records be identifiable as such in the new Access tables.'

Answer (score 0):

You could just import the tables in Access...and work your way using them as blueprint.
Just ensure that the "table relations" are correct... i know that there isn't one but take the "logical" path...if you a table with a fieldName "FaxBookID" and you have a table "FaxBook" ...you know they are related